# I can no longer use forkjoin with rxjs 5.5.2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

Recently, I decided to migrate a big project that has been created from scratch with the "Quick Start" of Angular to a version using Angular CLI 1.5.5. Right now, I'm fixing the different issues that arise and I can't get to fix this one.

I read that it was better to use lettable operators of rxjs, which I did and it works very well. However, I also have these lines of code:

```js
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/forkjoin";

...

let piecesGrouping$: Observable<IGroupedPiece[]>[] = deliveries.map(delivery => this._pieceService.getGroupedPieces(delivery.pieces));

Observable
  .forkJoin(...piecesGrouping$)
  .subscribe((groups) => {
    groups.forEach((group, i) => deliveries[i].groupedPieces = group);

    resolve();
  });
```

They were working very well in the previous version that was using rxjs 5.4.3, now with rxjs 5.5.2, they don't anymore and I get the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'apply' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of
>   undefined

I tried to replace the spread operator by `piecesGrouping$[0], piecesGrouping$[1]` as the error does not say anything about `forkJoin` in itself, then I get:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8_rxjs_Observable**.a.forkJoin is not a function TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8_rxjs_Observable**.a.forkJoin is not a function

So it looks like that I'm importing `forkJoin` the wrong way. I tried to import it from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin" but it didn't work either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't use `Observable` patching, use `forkJoin` directly:

```
import {forkJoin} from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin";

forkJoin(...piecesGrouping$).subscribe()
```

[Check this resource](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/fork-join) to learn more about `forkJoin`.

Comment: @ssougnez, you're welcome. As I suggested, don't use patching imports. Use lettable operators for instance operators, and static operators directly.

Comment: Thanks Max,in my case, I am using ' import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/Observable/forkJoin'  which is wrong.  please use  'import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin' ( 'O' is small in Observable).

Answer (score 6):

RxJS 6.x uses this import

`import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs'`;

As stated in the other answers, it still needs to be used as a function as it now stands on its own.  Docs are [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin)

Answer (score 5):

You should be using it as a function

```
forkJoin(...piecesGrouping$)
  .subscribe((groups) => {
    groups.forEach((group, i) => deliveries[i].groupedPieces = group);

    resolve();
  });
```

import statement is changed as

```
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin";
```

This was released as  a part of `5.2` version . Read the **[change log](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/compare/5.1.1...v5.2.0)**

Comment: Thanks, it works, although I'll accept the answer of "AngularInDepth.com" as he also put the modified import line.